# Firing triggered send via rest API - erring

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, triggered-send, installedpackage

I am trying to fire a triggered send REST API via postman, I have successfully created a package with all the permissions ticked, including email send,write. After generating the access token in the postman, try to fire the below-triggered send via the postman.
1046 is the external key of the triggered send. I have removed the tenant URL from the below link.

```
POST https://TENANTURLFROMPACKAGE.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/1046/send

in the body posting the following payload
{
    "To": {
        "SubscriberKey": "test@test.com",
        "Address": "test@test.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "EmailAddress": "test@test.com",
                "SubscriberKey": "test@test.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

However I am getting the below error

> 403 Forbidden

Please note that triggered send is in a running state, and I was able to fire it successfully from AMPSCRIPT via cloudpages.

Answer (score 0):

In the postman for the authorisation setting it was defaulted to inherit from parent. When I updated the authorisation setting to bearer, then it resolved the issue.